# I want to split this list after "::" and wanted to print only characters which comes after "::" in all entries

Tags: python, list, split

I want to split this list after "::" and wanted to print only characters which comes after "::" in all entries.

```
a=["Hi :: Abhishek","Hi :: Ashish","Hi :: Arnav","Hi :: Saurabh"]

b=str(a.split("::")[1])
```

Comment: Your idea to use `.split("::")[1]` was great! However, you shouldn't apply this to `a` as a whole, but to every element of `a`. For this you can use list comprehensions. List comprehensions provide syntax for applying an operation to every element of a list. For instance, try this: `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [2*x for x in a]`. And thus for your problem, replacing `2*x` from my example with `x.split('::')[1]`...

Comment: How strict is the input format? Is the delimiter *always* space-colon-colon-space, or can the whitespace around the `::` vary?

Comment: wow thanks buddy I will definitely try this one as you have suggested and input is not that strict its just only fixed list with already defined entries and I just want to split all entries after "::" sign only, However as you have suggested I will definitely work on this thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
res = [x.split('::')[1] for x in a]

print (res)
[' Abhishek', ' Ashish', ' Arnav', ' Saurabh']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve this by doing so:

```
[x.split('::')[1].strip() for x in a]
```

Output :

```
['Abhishek', 'Ashish', 'Arnav', 'Saurabh']
```

Comment: I think the intent was to get the entire word after `::`, not just the first character; you can drop the `[0]`.

Comment: hmm yes exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

In python you can do this in multiple ways. some of them are below.

**Using `split`**

```py
[i.split("::")[1] for i in a]
```

**Using `index`**

```py
[i[i.index("::")+2:] for i in a]
```

**Using `regex`**

```py
[re.match("^.*?::(.*?)$",i)[1] for i in a]
```

**Using `map` and `split`**

```py
list(map(lambda x: x.split("::")[1],a))
```

All of them produces same result

```
[' Abhishek', ' Ashish', ' Arnav', ' Saurabh']
```

If you don't want space in the begining, you can `strip()` it.

Comment: Thank you for providing all possible options for this :)